# 1. Create a sequence of number from 10 and 20 and assign it to variable M. 2.Identify the position of values greater than 13 and less than 20

Tags: r, fresco

I have tried below code , but it is showing not accurate answers

```
M = seq(10,20)
print(which(M > 13 & M<20))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correctly showing *position* of elements. See?

```
> print(which(M > 13 & M<20))
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10   <-- position of elements

> M[which(M > 13 & M<20)]
[1] 14 15 16 17 18 19   <-- actual values
```